# Multiple Variations of Firebase Timestamps

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I store a list of users invited to an organisation, together with the timestamp denoting when the invite expires in Firebase. When I pull the timestamp from Firebase, I parse it to determine if it's still valid or has expired using:

**Client Code**

```
const inviteStatus = invitee?.validUntil.toDate() >= Date.now() ? 'valid_invitee' : 'expired_invitee'
```

I have also built in functionality to generate new invites via a call to Firebase Cloud Functions. Once an invite has been created, I return a new invitee object:

**Firebase Functions Code**

```
const expiryDate = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toDate()
expiryDate.setTime(expiryDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) // 7-day expiration

return {
    invitee: {
        validUntil: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(expiryDate)
    }
}
```

The reason I don't return just a `Date` object but instead convert it to Firestore's `Timestamp` format is to ensure that client always receives the `validUntil` data in the same format, regardless of whether it's read directly from Firestore DB or returned via Firebase Cloud Functions.

However, once this invitee object is returned and the client code runs (see first code snippet), I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: invitee.validUntil.toDate is not a function

**Investigating**

I have printed both objects (one directly pulled from DB and another returned via Cloud Functions) and noticed that the object returned directly from DB, when printed, shows a *ut* in Chrome Dev Tools next to the `validUntil` object, whereas the object returned from Cloud Functions does not display *ut*.

*Printed Object Queried from Firestore*
[image]

*Printed Object Returned from Cloud Functions*
[image]

**Question**

Why is Firebase generating two different types of timestamp objects where one can be converted to `Date` using `.toDate()` function and another throws an error?

Is there a way to return a proper timestamp object via Cloud Functions that I will be able to apply `.toDate()` function on in the client?

Comment: "the object returned from Cloud Functions does not display ut" I think the information is probably lost in the marshaling of the timestamp. Can you edit your question to show the entire (but minimal) Cloud Function that returns the value to the user somehow?